# If $(x_n )\rightarrow a $ show that $ \sqrt[3]{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt[3]{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know $(x_n) \rightarrow a$ means that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ so that when $n\geq N$, $|x-a|<\epsilon$.

So I want to start with $|x-a| = |(\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{a})(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{ax}+ \sqrt[3]{a^2})|$

Where can I get with this by keeping $\epsilon <1$, i.e. $V_\epsilon (c) =(c-1,c+1)$. Can I say that $(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{ax}+ \sqrt[3]{a^2}) \leq(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a^2}+ \sqrt[3]{a^2}) = 3\sqrt[3]{a^2}$, since $x \rightarrow a$ and $\epsilon <3$?

This still confuses me but I think I'm on the right track. I hope someone can help me understand this. (it is not a homework problem, by the way).

Thanks!

Comment: No your inequality is wrong. Notice that a convergent sequence is bounded sequence so let $M$ such that $|x_n|\le M$ and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the case $a \neq 0$ separately.

Then if $|x - a| < |a|/2$ we have $|x| > |a|/2$ and

$$|x^{1/3} - a^{1/3}| = \frac{|x-a|}{x^{2/3} + x^{1/3} a^{1/3} + a^{2/3} } \\ \leqslant  \frac{|x-a|}{a^{2/3}(1/2^{2/3} + 1/2^{1/3}) }.$$

Now  if $|x- a| < \min\left\{|a|/2, \epsilon[a^{2/3}(1/2^{2/3} + 1/2^{1/3})]^{-1}\right\},$  then

$$|x^{1/3} - a^{1/3}| < \epsilon$$