# Show that $f(x) = x^{m}$ is continuous for $m$ rational.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider the function $f(x) = x^{m}$ with $m$ rational.

Show that $f$ is continuous on all nonnegative numbers when $m$ is positive and that $f$ is continuous on all positive numbers when $m$ is negative.

Could we use the fact that $m = p(1/q)$ in order to show that $f$ is the inverse of a function that is continuous on the desired interval?

Overall, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, the *inverse* of $x^{p/q}$ is $x^{q/p}$ so, as you said it, you are in need of a further argument.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Well, wouldn't we have $f(x) = x^{p/q} = (x^{p})^{1/q}$, so that $f^{-1} (x) =  (x^{p})^{q}$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 No, $f^{-1}(x)$ would be $(x^q)^{1/p}$.  You're on the right track but you're not inverting the right function.  Also, you should be more explicit about what theorem allows you to conclude that the inverse of a continuous function is continuous.

Comment: @ErickWong Oh, right. That's my mistake. Then, I'm not sure where my idea leads.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 If you can show that $x^{1/q}$ is continuous, then $x^{p/q}$ is just the product of $p$ continuous functions (when $p$ is positive).  Alternatively it is the composition of the continuous functions $x^p$ and $x^{1/q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$|x^p - c^p| = |x - c||x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}c + \ldots + xc^{p-2} + c^{p-1}|, \\ |x - c| = |x^{1/q} - c^{1/q}||x^{(q-1)/q} + x^{(q-2)/q}c^{1/q} + \ldots + x^{1/q}c^{(q-2)/q} +  c^{(q-1)/q}|. $$

To prove $f:x \mapsto x^p$ (p > 0) is continuous, we want to find $\delta$ such that $|x-c|< \delta \implies |x^p - c^p| < \epsilon$.

We have $|x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}c + \ldots + xc^{p-2} + c^{p-1}| \leqslant |x|^{p-1} + |x|^{p-2}|c| + \ldots + |x||c|^{p-2} + |c|^{p-1} $ by the triangle inequality.

If $|x - c| < 1$, then $|x| < 1 + |c|$ and $|x|^{p-1-j}|c|^j < (1 + |c|)^{p-1}.$

Hence,

$$|x^p - c^p| = |x - c||x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}c + \ldots + xc^{p-2} + c^{p-1}| < |x-c|p(1 +|c|)^{p-1},$$

and if $|x-c| < \min(1, \epsilon/[p(1 +|c|)^{p-1}])$, then $|x^p - c^p| < \epsilon.$

Similarly, we can prove $g:x \mapsto x^{1/q}$  using the second identity with a lower bound on the second factor on the RHS. (See [If $(x_n )\rightarrow a $ show that $ \sqrt[3]{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt[3]{a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1779942/148510).)

Finally, $h: x \mapsto f(g(x)) = x^{p/q}$ is the composition of continuous functions and, therefore, is continuous.

Comment: I'm not sure how you algebraically get from the first to second line. Sorry, I'm not sure how to use your hint.

Comment: They are separate identities.  You can use the first to show that $x^p$ is continuous with an $\epsilon - \delta$ argument since the second factor on the RHS is bounded independently of $x$ when $|x - c| < 1$.  Similarly, use the second result to show that $x^{1/q}$ is continuous and then show $(x^{1/q})^p$ is continuous by composition. Or set up a similar identity for $|x^{p/q} - c^{p/q}|$.

Comment: Ok, should the second identity you wrote be $|x^{1/q}−c^{1/q}| = |x−c||x^{(q−1)/q}+x^{(q−2)/q}c^{1/q}+…+x^{1/q}c^{(q−2)/q}+c^{(q−1)/q}|$?

Comment: No -- that is not correct.  Multiplying $x$ by $x^{(q-1)/q},$ when distributing, yields $x^{2 - 1/q}$ for example.  Use the second identity as is and find a lower bound for the second factor on the RHS as in the link.  Then rearrange as $|x^{1/q} - c^{1/q}| = |x-q|/| \ldots|$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: @CuriousKid7: You're welcome.

Comment: When you write $|x|^{p−1−j}|c|^{j} < (1+|c|)^{p−1}$, are you assuming that $p$ is positive?

Comment: Yes.  I'll add that.  If $m$ is negative then you can view this as showing $(1/x)^{|m|}$ is continuous. This follows from the previous result and composition with the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ which is continuous when $x \neq 0$.  Just more details needed.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But when it's positive, we have that $x^p$ is a polynomial, so that we know it's continuous, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a general fact that proves that all sorts of reasonable functions are continuous:

**Lemma**.Let $I$ and $J$ be open intervals in $\Bbb R$, and let $f:I\to J$ be surjective and strictly monotone. Then $f$ is continuous.

**Proof**: Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $f$ is increasing. Let $x\in I$, $y=f(x)$ its image in $J$. Start with a positive $\varepsilon$, I’ll show you how to get your $\delta$. Since $J$ is open, we can assume without loss of generality that $y-\varepsilon$ and $y+\varepsilon$ both are in $J$, and therefore there are $x_-\in I$ and $x_+\in I$ with $f(x_-)=y-\varepsilon$, $f(x_+)=y+\varepsilon$ (because $f$ is surjective) and satisfying $x_-<x<x_+$ (because $f$ is increasing). Now let $\delta=\min(x-x_-,x_+-x)$. That’s it, ’cause if $|x-\xi|<\delta$, then $\xi$ is between $x_-$ and $x_+$, and $f(\xi)$ is between $f(x_-)=y-\varepsilon$ and $f(x_+)=y+\varepsilon$, in other words, $|f(\xi)-y|<\varepsilon$. q.e.d.

Your function $x\mapsto x^{p/q}$ is strictly monotone on $\langle0,\infty\rangle$ (unless $p/q=0$) and surjective, so continuous by the Lemma.

Comment: Why can we assume WLOG that $y-\epsilon$, $y+\epsilon$ are both in $J$? $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, right?

Comment: If the proof is accomplished for a smaller epsilon, then it’s accomplished for the given epsilon.